# How to list all CNN classification models from torchvision?

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I list all CNN classification models from torchvision?

I can do something like:

```
import torchvision
dir(torchvision.models)
```

but it produce not only models classes names:

```
['AlexNet',
 'AlexNet_Weights',
 'ConvNeXt',
 'ConvNeXt_Base_Weights',
 'ConvNeXt_Large_Weights',
 'ConvNeXt_Small_Weights',
 'ConvNeXt_Tiny_Weights',
 'DenseNet',
 'DenseNet121_Weights',
 'DenseNet161_Weights',
 'DenseNet169_Weights',
 'DenseNet201_Weights',
 'EfficientNet',
 'EfficientNet_B0_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B1_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B2_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B3_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B4_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B5_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B6_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_B7_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_V2_L_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_V2_M_Weights',
 'EfficientNet_V2_S_Weights',
 'GoogLeNet',
 'GoogLeNetOutputs',
 'GoogLeNet_Weights',
 'Inception3',
 'InceptionOutputs',
 'Inception_V3_Weights',
 'MNASNet',
 'MNASNet0_5_Weights',
 'MNASNet0_75_Weights',
 'MNASNet1_0_Weights',
 'MNASNet1_3_Weights',
 'MaxVit',
 'MaxVit_T_Weights',
 'MobileNetV2',
 'MobileNetV3',
 'MobileNet_V2_Weights',
 'MobileNet_V3_Large_Weights',
 'MobileNet_V3_Small_Weights',
 'RegNet',
 'RegNet_X_16GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_1_6GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_32GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_3_2GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_400MF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_800MF_Weights',
 'RegNet_X_8GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_128GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_16GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_1_6GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_32GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_3_2GF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_400MF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_800MF_Weights',
 'RegNet_Y_8GF_Weights',
 'ResNeXt101_32X8D_Weights',
 'ResNeXt101_64X4D_Weights',
 'ResNeXt50_32X4D_Weights',
 'ResNet',
 'ResNet101_Weights',
 'ResNet152_Weights',
 'ResNet18_Weights',
 'ResNet34_Weights',
 'ResNet50_Weights',
 'ShuffleNetV2',
 'ShuffleNet_V2_X0_5_Weights',
 'ShuffleNet_V2_X1_0_Weights',
 'ShuffleNet_V2_X1_5_Weights',
 'ShuffleNet_V2_X2_0_Weights',
 'SqueezeNet',
 'SqueezeNet1_0_Weights',
 'SqueezeNet1_1_Weights',
 'SwinTransformer',
 'Swin_B_Weights',
 'Swin_S_Weights',
 'Swin_T_Weights',
 'Swin_V2_B_Weights',
 'Swin_V2_S_Weights',
 'Swin_V2_T_Weights',
 'VGG',
 'VGG11_BN_Weights',
 'VGG11_Weights',
 'VGG13_BN_Weights',
 'VGG13_Weights',
 'VGG16_BN_Weights',
 'VGG16_Weights',
 'VGG19_BN_Weights',
 'VGG19_Weights',
 'ViT_B_16_Weights',
 'ViT_B_32_Weights',
 'ViT_H_14_Weights',
 'ViT_L_16_Weights',
 'ViT_L_32_Weights',
 'VisionTransformer',
 'Weights',
 'WeightsEnum',
 'Wide_ResNet101_2_Weights',
 'Wide_ResNet50_2_Weights',
 '_GoogLeNetOutputs',
 '_InceptionOutputs',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '_api',
 '_meta',
 '_utils',
 'alexnet',
 'convnext',
 'convnext_base',
 'convnext_large',
 'convnext_small',
 'convnext_tiny',
 'densenet',
 'densenet121',
 'densenet161',
 'densenet169',
 'densenet201',
 'detection',
 'efficientnet',
 'efficientnet_b0',
 'efficientnet_b1',
 'efficientnet_b2',
 'efficientnet_b3',
 'efficientnet_b4',
 'efficientnet_b5',
 'efficientnet_b6',
 'efficientnet_b7',
 'efficientnet_v2_l',
 'efficientnet_v2_m',
 'efficientnet_v2_s',
 'get_model',
 'get_model_builder',
 'get_model_weights',
 'get_weight',
 'googlenet',
 'inception',
 'inception_v3',
 'list_models',
 'maxvit',
 'maxvit_t',
 'mnasnet',
 'mnasnet0_5',
 'mnasnet0_75',
 'mnasnet1_0',
 'mnasnet1_3',
 'mobilenet',
 'mobilenet_v2',
 'mobilenet_v3_large',
 'mobilenet_v3_small',
 'mobilenetv2',
 'mobilenetv3',
 'optical_flow',
 'quantization',
 'regnet',
 'regnet_x_16gf',
 'regnet_x_1_6gf',
 'regnet_x_32gf',
 'regnet_x_3_2gf',
 'regnet_x_400mf',
 'regnet_x_800mf',
 'regnet_x_8gf',
 'regnet_y_128gf',
 'regnet_y_16gf',
 'regnet_y_1_6gf',
 'regnet_y_32gf',
 'regnet_y_3_2gf',
 'regnet_y_400mf',
 'regnet_y_800mf',
 'regnet_y_8gf',
 'resnet',
 'resnet101',
 'resnet152',
 'resnet18',
 'resnet34',
 'resnet50',
 'resnext101_32x8d',
 'resnext101_64x4d',
 'resnext50_32x4d',
 'segmentation',
 'shufflenet_v2_x0_5',
 'shufflenet_v2_x1_0',
 'shufflenet_v2_x1_5',
 'shufflenet_v2_x2_0',
 'shufflenetv2',
 'squeezenet',
 'squeezenet1_0',
 'squeezenet1_1',
 'swin_b',
 'swin_s',
 'swin_t',
 'swin_transformer',
 'swin_v2_b',
 'swin_v2_s',
 'swin_v2_t',
 'vgg',
 'vgg11',
 'vgg11_bn',
 'vgg13',
 'vgg13_bn',
 'vgg16',
 'vgg16_bn',
 'vgg19',
 'vgg19_bn',
 'video',
 'vision_transformer',
 'vit_b_16',
 'vit_b_32',
 'vit_h_14',
 'vit_l_16',
 'vit_l_32',
 'wide_resnet101_2',
 'wide_resnet50_2']
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only printing the dir() function. You need to create a for loop that use the dir() function to generate a list of all the attributes in the models module but then filters the generated list to include only attributes with lowercase names that start with the names of the CNN classification models.

I've made this for you to try:

```
import torchvision.models as models


def gen_models():
    classification_models_name = []
    for name in dir(models):
        if name.islower() and (name.startswith('resnet') or 
                               name.startswith('densenet') or 
                               name.startswith('inception') or 
                               name.startswith('mnasnet') or 
                               name.startswith('mobilenet') or 
                               name.startswith('shufflenet') or 
                               name.startswith('googlenet') or
                               name.startswith('squeezenet') or 
                               name.startswith('vgg')):
            classification_models_name.append(name)
    return classification_models_name


print(gen_models())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I came up with:

```
import torchvision.models as models
model_names = sorted(name for name in models.__dict__
                     if name.islower()
                     and not name.startswith("__") and not name.startswith('get_') and not name.startswith('list_')
                     and callable(models.__dict__[name]))
```

this gives me 80 models on

```
torch.__version__:  2.0.0
torchvision.__version__:  0.15.0
```

some of which are kinda transformer based, but still it's suitable for imagenet classification tasks, so I think it's ok.

Or alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision.models import list_models
model_names = list_models(module=torchvision.models)
```